# SUM if header row dones't contain a substring AND range doesn't contain #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumifs, sumproduct

In Column A I want to sum all the cells in range B2:J2 that their header row doesn't contain the word "Price", also one of the cells in range B2:J2 might be #N/A.

In the example I shared only the cells that are highlighted in grey are relevant, and the formula should return 5.

I would love to get your help.

[image: attached image]

Comment: What's the content of the mentioned cells? Values, formulas, ..., did you do any formula auditing?

Comment: Hi Dominique, The content is always numbers (in the cells that i want), how can formula auditing help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array formula with `SUM`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("price",$B$1:$J$1)))*(B2:J2),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. but what about the part where one or more of the cells in range B2:J2 might be #N/A ?

Comment: @Kobe2424 This is solved by the ```IFERROR``` function.